# Cossine of a standard Normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1) $ have a standard normal distribution. How do I compute 
$$\mathbb{E}[cos(X)] \text{ ?}$$
I know that $$\mathbb{E}[sin(X)] = 0$$
because $$f(x)=sin(x) \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$$
is an odd function. Can I use this fact to compute $\mathbb{E}[cos(X)]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Examples) $\Bbb Ee^{itX}=e^{-t^2/2}$, $\Bbb E\cos X=\Re\left.\Bbb Ee^{itX}\right|_{t=1}=e^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Well characteristic functions made this a lot easier... Thank you!